# Factory with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have simple factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event_with_tags do
    name 'event-name'
    start_date '2016-03-16'
    start_time '11:34'
    tags = %w(foo bar)
    after(:create) do |event|
      tags.each do |tag|
        event.tags << create(:tag, name: tag)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to create factory in such a way, that I can use it like this or something similiar?:

`FactoryGirl.create(:event_with_tags, tags: 'foo bar qux')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You should use [Transient Attributes](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Transient_Attributes) i.e. declare `tags` as transient attribute.